# how to write json response in json file in Zerocode

Tags: java, automated-tests, integration-testing, junit5, rest-assured

I am trying to run test with Junit(4) using Zerocode. I was able to run existing Junit test classes by following these tutorials

```
https://github.com/authorjapps/zerocode-hello-world/blob/master/src/test/resources/helloworld_more/hello_world_all_integrated_apis.json
```

I have a Junit test suite working properly and I would like to know how to use zerocode to write api response in json file. 
The examples above are describing how to run a selected test and verification api response and how to use response in next test.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the tests, zerocode will generate logs in `target` folder. Inside target folder, please check logs folder. You cannot just pick the responses and forward them into some file.